# Pyscopg2 binary install into windows anaconda environment

Tags: python, psycopg2, anaconda

I am trying to install the psycopg2 package using the windows binary installer (for several reasons I need to use the binary installer) on a stand alone Windows 7 machine. I can successfully install the package into the root environment but cannot see it in my Anacaonda virtual environment.

Is there a way to install a binary executable package directly into a virtual environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with it once (with different package, though). The best solution I found was to make symbolic link from my root `site-packages` to those of `virtualenv`:

```
mklink /D <path-to-virtualenv>/site-packages/psycopg2 <path-to-root-python-distribution>/site-packages/psycopg2
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, I will try that now.

Comment: Forgot to say that you have to do it in `cmd` run with admin rights.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I also found that copying from the psycopg2 folder from site-packages into the virtual env worked.